# VBA Excel HMACSHA256 function returns incorrect digest

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to implement HMACSHA256 encoding in Excel VBA.

Several [examples/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246340/does-vba-have-a-hash-hmac) make use of `System.Text.UTF8Encoding` & `System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256` however I'm using Windows 10/Office 365 which results in an automation error due to the .NET 4.6 framework (per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39339946/vba-excel-automation-error-from-sha256-and-hmacsha256-functions)).

There does appear to be an [existing VB6 implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453409/hmac-sha256-macro-in-excel/28453704#28453704), however it makes use of various Windows libraries which I'd rather avoid as my code may need to run on Office for Mac. I'm also interested in implementing this from first principles as a learning experience.

[Per mikegrann's comment on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39339946/vba-excel-automation-error-from-sha256-and-hmacsha256-functions#comment66039175_39339946) I decide to write my own HMAC wrapper on top of an existing [SHA256 class module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22672564/porting-sha-256-library-to-excel?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Using the [spec](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/79577/whats-the-difference-between-hmac-sha256key-data-and-sha256key-data/79579#79579) and [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code#Implementation) which Mike linked to in his comment I came up with the below code which I added to the SHA256 class module.

```
Public Function HMAC_SHA256(MessageString As String, KeyString As String) As String

    Dim KeyByteArray() As Byte
    Dim iKeyPadByteArray(63) As Byte, oKeyPadByteArray(63) As Byte
    Dim iKeyPadString As String, oKeyPadString As String
    Dim i As Long

    'ensure key is same size as BLOCKSIZE (64)
    If Len(KeyString) > BLOCKSIZE Then KeyString = SHA256 (KeyString) 'hash to reduce to 64 bytes

    If Len(KeyString) < BLOCKSIZE Then KeyString = KeyString & _
    String(BLOCKSIZE - Len(KeyString), &H0) 'add 0x00 padding

    'convert key to byte array
    KeyByteArray = StrConv(KeyString, vbFromUnicode)

    'create iKeyPad & oKeyPad by Xor'ing with key
    For i = 0 To 63

        iKeyPadByteArray(i) = KeyByteArray(i) Xor &H36 'ipad is the byte 0x36 repeated 64 times
        oKeyPadByteArray(i) = KeyByteArray(i) Xor &H5C 'opad is the byte 0x5c repeated 64 times

    Next i

    'convert back to string for use in SHA256 function
    iKeyPadString = StrConv(iKeyPadByteArray, vbUnicode)
    oKeyPadString = StrConv(oKeyPadByteArray, vbUnicode)

    'generate hash
    HMAC_SHA256 = SHA256(oKeyPadString & SHA256(iKeyPadString & MessageString))

End Function
```

`SHA256` is the main function defined in the [class module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22672564/porting-sha-256-library-to-excel?noredirect=1&lq=1)

When I call the function it returns a correctly formatted but incorrect HMACSHA256 digest.

```
Sub foo()

    Dim SourceString As String, KeyVal As String
    Dim foo As CSHA256

    SourceString = "what do ya want for nothing?"
    KeyVal = "Jefe"

    Set foo = New CSHA256
    Debug.Print "HMAC_SHA256: " & foo.HMAC_SHA256(SourceString, KeyVal)
    Debug.Print "SHA256: " & foo.SHA256(SourceString)

End Sub
```

output:

```
HMAC_SHA256: 1fa93aea23d7b353ef468e5ac460b2840c694842e7ac2018d58a7bf5b790b6e3
SHA256: b381e7fec653fc3ab9b178272366b8ac87fed8d31cb25ed1d0e1f3318644c89c
```

the SHA256 digest is correct, I've verified it against the test vectors in the spec and with online generators. however the HMAC256 digest is incorrect, it should be...

```
5bdcc146bf60754e6a042426089575c75a003f089d2739839dec58b964ec3843
```

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong with the HMAC wrapper as there is not much happening. The 2 areas I thought might be the cause are the conversion to/from byte array and the Xor'ing with iPad & oPad.

I have verified the byte array conversion doesn't include trailing 0s

[Screen Grab of Locals Window showing KeyByteArray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwGhz.png)

I also tried converting the byte values to binary and applying an bit-level XOR operation on them; however this resulted in the same output as performing it on the byte array so I don't think that is an issue.

Any help/advice where I might be going wrong gratefully appreciated.

======== EDIT ========

Editing post following on from exchange with @A.S.H in the comments.

I have been researching/experimenting with string/byte conversion as I agree this is the most likely candidate as to where the error lies.

```
Sub StringByteExperiments()

    Dim KeyString As String, i As Long
    Dim ByteArr_UTF8() As Byte, ByteArr_UTF16() As Byte
    Dim ByteArr_UTF32() As Byte, ByteArr_ASC(3) As Byte

    KeyString = "Jefe"

    '=== String to Byte Array ===
    ByteArr_UTF8 = StrConv(KeyString, vbFromUnicode)
                '=> {74,101,102,101}
    ByteArr_UTF16 = KeyString
                '=> {74,0,101,0,102,0,101,0}
    ByteArr_UTF32 = StrConv(KeyString, vbUnicode)
                '=> {74,0,0,0,101,0,0,0,102,0,0,0,101,0,0,0}
    For i = 1 To Len(KeyString)
        ByteArr_ASC(i - 1) = AscW(Mid(KeyString, i, 1))
    Next i
                '=> {74,101,102,101}

    '=== Byte Array to String ===
    KeyString = StrConv(ByteArr_UTF8, vbUnicode)
            '=> "Jefe"
    KeyString = ByteArr_UT16
            '=> doesn't compile
    KeyString = Join(ByteArr_UTF16)
            '=> err #5, invalid procedure call or argument
    KeyString = StrConv(ByteArr_UTF16, vbFromUnicode)
            '=> "??" can't parse
    KeyString = StrConv(ByteArr_UTF16, vbUnicode)
            '=> "J e f e "
    KeyString = StrConv(ByteArr_UTF32, vbFromUnicode)
            '=> "Jefe"
    KeyString = StrConv(ByteArr_UTF32, vbUnicode)
            '=> "J   e   f   e   "
    KeyString = vbNullString
    For i = LBound(ByteArr_ASC) To UBound(ByteArr_ASC)
        KeyString = KeyString & Chr(ByteArr_ASC(i))
    Next i
            '=> "Jefe"

End Sub
```

@A.S.H suggested directly assigning the string to the byte array, doing this appears to result in a UTF16 byte array i.e. each character is 2 bytes.

Does this mean VBA natively encodes strings in UTF16? `Len(KeyString)` returns 4 whereas `LenB(KeyString)` returns 8, which would indicate 2 bytes per character.

I have tried decoding to a UTF16 byte array (i.e. with the trailing zero) and using that for the iPad & oPad Xor operation then convert back, but it still results in an incorrect digest.

As I understand it HMAC_SHA256 works with UTF8 byte arrays, and that appears to be what my current function is doing so am at a loss as what the error could be.

Is anyone able to point me to a resource/method where I could determine the correct UTF8 byte array for a known key value and also the correct post-Xor-operation byte array & string value for iPad & oPad. This would allow me to compare with my function at various steps along the way to help track down the problem.

Thanks

~a

Comment: `If Len(KeyString) > BLOCKSIZE Then SHA256(KeyString)` don't you mean here `If Len(KeyString) > BLOCKSIZE Then KeyString = SHA256(KeyString)` ?

Comment: yes I did - thank you @A.S.H, although this doesn't appear to the root cause of the incorrect digest; in the test case this `If...Then` clause was not being run as the KeyString length is/was under the `BLOCKSIZE` (64 bytes).

Comment: Yep, I knew that (the key you're testing is "Jefe"). My suspicions for the moment are to those `StrConv` conversions. Basically, what we want is to convert (back and forth) the string data type to a byte array data type *without changing anything to the data*. Are you so sure that these conversions achieve exactly that?...

Comment: And By the way, the resulting MAC is a binary, it is not a printable string... unless it is converted to `BASE64` encoding.

Comment: The `StringKeyByteArray` after padding comprises `{74,101,102,101,0,0, …}` which appears to corelate to the correct ASCII codes for "J", "e", "f" & "e".

After Xor'ing with iPad `{54, 54, 54, …}` the resulting `iPadKeyByteArray` is `{124, 83, 80, 83, 54, 54, 54, …}` and Xor'ing with oPad `{92, 92, 92, …}` the resulting `oPadKeyByteArray` is `{22, 57, 58, 57, 92, 92, 92, …}`

I manually converted the values to binary and used the Xor truth table to produce the result by hand and they all seem to be correct.

Comment: After the `StrConv` the `iKeyPadString` is `|SPS666…` and the `oKeyPadString` is `¿9:9\\\…`

the first character of `oKeyPadString` is ASCII code 22, which is a control character (Synchronous idle) that VBA can't display. I don't _think_ this is causing an issue as if I convert back to a byte array it retains it's value. I also tried amending the `StringKey` to "efe" to avoid generating that value as a result and the digest was still incorrect.

Comment: Why don't you give it a try with direct assignments instead of `StrConv`? `KeyByteArray = KeyString`, `iKeyPadString = iKeyPadByteArray`, etc.?